# How to refresh/redirect page after some seconds in Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, refresh

I came across to an obstacle for me when i wanted to output a message for couple seconds in the page then redirect the user after to a different page.
 i know we can do it with plain php as in  `header("Refresh:4; url=http://www.targeturl.com");`
How can i do the same thing in Zend Framework?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put a sleep before the redirect

```
sleep(4);
$this->view->_redirect('http://www.targeturl.com');
```

or use meta refresh

```
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Refresh', '4;URL=http://www.targeturl.com');
```

I think the latter is what you are after.

Comment: sleep(4);
$this->view->_redirect('http://www.targeturl.com');

when i use this it does not wait 4 seconds, it just redirects without waiting.

Comment: Did you try the second?

Comment: it gives me an error that it is not trapped in something
i used the plain php header() function

Comment: i tied the second but changed it a little bit. i will post the answer after i complete and test it all the way.


thank you.